# Is this layout nested weight or not?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

Android studio always say "Nested weights are bad for performance"
I create this nested with a trick (a container with match_parent,match_parent)

my questions is:
is this nested? and is my layout standard? or I just fooled android studio with that container?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Head"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <LinearLayout

           android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="right"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="left"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Foot"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, it is nested. What are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a Layout with header and footer and split the main to two container (30% and 70%)...

Comment: why don't you try `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: Looks fine to me, what issue are you having? Although, your foot and head have irrelevant linearlayout wrappers on them, they could simply be on their own without the parent linear layouts. Other then that, I don't see an issue, but I'm guessing your button wrapper is just pseudo to get your design point across. Performance would not be bad enough to notice nested weight issue.

Comment: I think LinearLayouts are faster and have better performance in different sizes and lower apis

Answer (score 1):

All you've done is trick the lint. If you made the true parent's orientation horizontal like it should be, Android Studio would also warn of a useless parent.

However, while nested weights may be bad for performance, unless every layout you're using is full of nested weights, you probably won't notice it. Don't use them if you can avoid it, but it's not the end of the world if you do.